# Wpf- binding tooltip to a column having comma separated values to be show as a list

Tags: wpf, binding, tooltip

How can I display tool tip as a list of values binded to one of the column of a grid having comma separated string value in WPF.
I can bind it to a column which is showing comma separated values.

```
<ctl:FieldHelp.Columns>   
            <data:DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding ID, Mode=TwoWay}"  IsReadOnly="True">  
               <data:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>  
                    <Style TargetType="data:DataGridCell" >  
                        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip" Value="{Binding Details}"></Setter>  
                    </Style>  
                </data:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>  
            </data:DataGridTextColumn>  
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>  
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Comment: displaying part of your code is the best way to have a good answer

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a value converter. You can bind the tooltip to the column but it is showing the comma seperated string of values and you want it to show the values as a list. Using a value converter you can replace the comma with a line break character \n

Comment: yes @ooomdtski, But I don't have idea on how to use the converter ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a value converter. You hav to create a class which implements the IValueConverter interface.

```cs
public class TooltipStringListConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Process your comma seperated string here
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // You can leave this empty
    }
}
```

In your XAML change

```
<Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip" Value="{Binding Details}"></Setter>
```

To this:

```
<Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip" Value="{Binding Details, Converter={StaticResource TooltipStringListConverter}}"></Setter>
```

Be sure that you use the correct namespace of the converter.
I have not tested it, but i'm sure this is the way to go.

Edit:

I forgot the include the converter in the xaml like Celso Livero did by adding

```xml
<Window ... 
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:NamespaceOfYourConverter"
>

<Window.Resources>
    <converters:TooltipStringListConverter x:Key="TooltipStringListConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, how to use a converter:

change:

`Value="{Binding Details}"` => `Value="{Binding Details, Converter={StaticResource CommaStringConverter}}"`

Create your converter

```
public class CommaStringConverter : BaseConverter, IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return string.Join("\n", value.Split(','));
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                                  object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
```

Add it to your `app.xaml` file

```
<Application 
             .....
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:YourAppNameSpace.YourConvertersFolder"
             ...... >
    <Application.Resources>

        <converters:CommaStringConverter  x:Key="CommaStringConverter " />

        ...........
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```